# Errors in Obj-C class in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a Swift project, now i added some Obj-C classes, before bridging anything i tried to compile the whole project and it failed, giving me errors in the Obj-C code in all the classes i have imported. Here is some of the errors

[image]

and here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the UIKit framework has not been added to your project.

Click on General tab of your target, and try to add UIKit in "Linked frameworks and libraries"

Answer (score 2):

The UIViewController class is part of the UIKit framework; you need

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```